# Windows Mobile v8.1 How do i retrieve datepicker and timepicker to a listbox?

Tags: c#, datepicker, listbox, timepicker

I'm kinda new here, so I would like to apologize if I have made any mistake.

My DateTimeReservation.xmal

```
<TextBlock Margin="0,161,259,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Date:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="59" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="131" FontSize="30" />
<TextBlock Margin="0,243,259,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Time:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="59" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="131" FontSize="30" />
<DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="243,154,0,0" YearVisible="True" x:Name="arrivalDatePicker" />
<TimePicker x:Name="Time1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="243,233,0,0" MinuteIncrement="30"/>
<Button Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="243,305,0,0" Click="Button_Click"/>
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,54,10,484" x:Name="Alert" FontSize="25"/>
```

My DateTimeReservation.xmal.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Time1.DataContext = e.Parameter;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Table), Time1);
}
```

The page that I want to retrieve my date and time to: Table.xmal

```
<ListBox BorderBrush="#FF141EE4" Height="auto" BorderThickness="2" MaxHeight="580" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="listBoxobj" SelectionChanged="listBoxobj_SelectionChanged" Background="Black">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="Gray" Width="480">
                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" x:Name="TableNoTxt" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Time}" FontSize="28" Foreground="White"/>                 
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Table.xmal.cs (I'm stuck at this part)

```
DatabaseHelperClass Db_Helper = new DatabaseHelperClass();
Reservation currentcontact = new Reservation();
```

My Model Reservation.cs

```
public int ReservationId { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string ContactNumber {get; set;}
    public string TableNo { get; set; }

    public Reservation()
    {
        //empty constructor
    }
    public Reservation(string tableno, string name)
    {
        TableNo = tableno;
        Name = name;



    }

    public Reservation(string tableno, string name, string contactnumber)
    {
        this.TableNo = tableno;
        this.Name = name;
        this.ContactNumber = contactnumber;


    }

    public Reservation(string tableno, string name, string contactnumber, string date, string time)
    {
        this.TableNo = tableno;
        this.Name = name;
        this.ContactNumber = contactnumber;
        this.Date = date;
        this.Time = time;

    }

    public Reservation(string tableno, string name, string contactnumber, string date)
    {
        this.TableNo = tableno;
        this.Name = name;
        this.ContactNumber = contactnumber;
        this.Date = date;


    }
```

And my database

```
public Reservation ReadDateTime(string datetime)
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            var existingDateTime = dbConn.Query<Reservation>("select * from Reservation where Date =" + datetime).FirstOrDefault();
            return existingDateTime;
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what is the problem exactly?

Comment: i couldn't retrieve my datepicker and timepicker from DateTimeReservation.xmal to Table.xmal